# How do i add contacts to lync 2010 api in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, lync, lync-2010

I am trying to develope an application that will help me import my contacts to lync 2010.

I am doing this program in VB.NET using the Lync 2010 SDK.

I am able to get all the users from the lync client to my application, but i am really struggling to find an solution to how i can add an contact to my lync client using my application.
Is this possible? If so, can anyone help me out? :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good starting point: [Walkthrough: Add and Remove Contacts in a Group (Lync 2010 SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh345240%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thank you. But that only tells me how to add them to groups, i am trying to import contacts to lync.